# Git rebase checks out parent commit

Tags: git, rebase

Git is behaving weirdly in a particular case and I am able to reproduce the issue. I have two branches, say master and feature, pointing to the same commit. When I reset the master to a parent commit and try to rebase feature on top of master, the feature branch also points to the parent commit although I expect rebase to do nothing. I am not sure why it's happening.

Steps to reproduce:

Run the following commands to reproduce the initial state:

```
deepakgupta @ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/hello/.git/

deepakgupta (master)@ touch hello

deepakgupta (master)@ git add hello

deepakgupta (master)@ git commit -m "First commit"
[master (root-commit) 1750f9c] First commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 hello

deepakgupta (master)@ touch world

deepakgupta (master)@ git add world

deepakgupta (master)@ git commit -m "Second commit"
[master 7411ad0] Second commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 world

deepakgupta (master)@ git branch feature
```

At this point of time, this is how `git log` looks:

```
commit 7411ad0984841b28dca630d54c3b079ebd01c7e9 (HEAD -> master, feature)
Author: Deepak Gupta <deepakguptacse@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 13:58:09 2020 +0530

    Second commit

commit 1750f9c5ba95f53742005657e9cee41390165dc7
Author: Deepak Gupta <deepakguptacse@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 13:57:54 2020 +0530

    First commit
```

Now try out:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git checkout feature
git branch --set-upstream-to master
```

This is now git log looks now:

```
commit 7411ad0984841b28dca630d54c3b079ebd01c7e9 (HEAD -> feature)
Author: Deepak Gupta <deepakguptacse@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 13:58:09 2020 +0530

    Second commit

commit 1750f9c5ba95f53742005657e9cee41390165dc7 (master)
Author: Deepak Gupta <deepakguptacse@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 13:57:54 2020 +0530

    First commit
```

What should happen when I try `git rebase`? I feel that the state should remain same.
but it changes to:

```
commit 1750f9c5ba95f53742005657e9cee41390165dc7 (HEAD -> feature, master)
Author: Deepak Gupta <deepak.gupta@rubrik.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 7 13:57:54 2020 +0530

    First commit
(END)
```

Can someone explain the behavior?

Comment: What exaclty is the `rebase` command you use, and which branch is checked out when you use it? Just `git rebase` without any parameters when having checked out `feature`?

Comment: @kowsky: he showed the actual command above (`git rebase` with no parameters), although it might have been clearer as a script. Note that fork-point mode for rebase was new in early Git 2.x releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem—or *feature*, as the Git folks prefer to refer to it—is due to Git's *fork-point mode*.  [The `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) describes this as follows:

> If *`upstream`* is not specified, the upstream configured in `branch.name.remote` and `branch.name.merge` options will be used (see [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for details) **and the `--fork-point` option is assumed**. If you are currently not on any branch or if the current branch does not have a configured upstream, the rebase will abort.

(formatting, especially the bold part, is mine here).  The next paragraph offers this cryptic summary:

> All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in *`upstream`* are saved to a temporary area. This is the same set of commits that would be shown by `git log <upstream>..HEAD`; or by `git log 'fork_point'..HEAD`, if `--fork-point` is active (see the description on `--fork-point` below); or by `git log HEAD`, if the `--root` option is specified.

(This description omits a few important items: in particular, merges and commits that are patch-ID equivalent are also discarded by default.  But neither of these affects your particular case.)

The fork-point description is partway down the page.  It mentions that:

> **`fork_point`** is the result of `git merge-base --fork-point <upstream> <branch>` command (see [git-merge-base[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)). If **`fork_point`** ends up being empty, the *`upstream`* will be used as a fallback.

The *`upstream`* is `master` and the *`branch`* is the current branch, `feature`.  In my repository, I now run:

```
$ git merge-base --fork-point master feature
af07c3c48ff0d499400ac539aa9c665a8dddcd6f
```

(using the hash IDs in the repository I made while reproducing your example).  Let's use `git log` on my repository to see the two commits:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline
af07c3c (HEAD -> feature) Second commit
dbf1741 (master) First commit
```

So, given this output from `git merge-base --fork-point`, `rebase` promises that the commits that it will copy are those that would be shown by `git log af07c3c48ff0d499400ac539aa9c665a8dddcd6f..HEAD`:

```
$ git log af07c3c48ff0d499400ac539aa9c665a8dddcd6f..HEAD
$
```

No commits are listed, so no commits are copied.

#### How to fix the problem

To *disable* fork-point mode, run:

```
git rebase --no-fork-point
```

or:

```
git rebase master
```

Even though the upstream of the current branch `feature` is `master`, an *explicit* `git rebase master` *disables* fork-point mode by default.  To force Git to use fork-point mode when using an explicit branch name—should you wish to do this; in this case, you presumably *don't* want it—you could also run:

```
git rebase --fork-point master
```

With no arguments at all, you get the effect of `git rebase --fork-point master`.